# Sencha Mysql Queries

Tags: sql, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm about to port an Android-Travellog App to other Plattforms using Sencha Touch.
The Problem is, that Sencha only has a Store System to store Data, but doesnt appear to have a possibilty to acctually make MySql queries.
And since most of the Mysql code in my previous app is already there, id would be quite a pain to redo everything with Senchas new System.
Is there a possibilty to use mysql (or any other sql) queries with Sencha to Store Data on the Phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha stores and proxies abstract away the need to write raw query code. A store can use one of a number of [different proxies](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/proxies) for interfacing with different back-end data stores, one of which is the [SQL proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Sql), which as you can see in the [source code](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/source/Sql.html#Ext-data-proxy-Sql) provides an API for basic data querying [WebSQL](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/) databases.

If you want to gain the full benefit of the framework and do things the "Sencha way" you'll probably want to start from scratch and architect your app to use the [stores API](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store).